# portlet/servlet abstraction

Tags: servlets, open-source, portlet, abstraction

is there a good library, that abstracts the differences between servlets/portlets/ concerning views?

Specifically I want to be able to write a view **once** and use it in a simple webapp or in a portlet. It may be a tag library, or a template language or whatever there is.

It should make development dead simple and reuse possible and abstract things like servlet session/portlet session, renderRequest/servletRequest/

Answer (score 0):

A portlet is a webapp. There could be some differences according to the Framework you use but you can write a "classic" java webapp then configure it to be a Portlet (with the portlet.xml and with a PortletBridge).

For example, if you use JSF, you can juste write a class which extends GenericPortlet and which will redirect each portlet action to your JSF lifecycle. You can use the JBoss PortletBridge for example.

There is also IceFaces for JSF portlets. But you can also use any Framework (Struts2, Struts, Vaadin etc.).

Hope it helps.